# List of books in which at the end I can understand most mathematical symbols

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am so sorry if my question seems selfish. There are already so many existing questions asking for a list of books to better learn math is some way or another.

This is a list of all the math symbols:

https://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.html

Can anyone recommend a short list, possibly of 10-20 books (for beginners or easy to read) in which through learning their subjects, at the end I will have a basic understanding with at least most symbols?

Update: My knowledge ends with high school symbols: Basic Algebra, Basic Geometry and Basic calculus. I was very good in math in high school, but my life took another direction. I am very good at understanding theorems, but in a very procedural fashion. I would like to close the gap with better understanding of symbols.

If it helps to understand what my goal is: my goal is to read these books and be able to come back to this forum and understand most questions in this forum (not necessarily their answers). From there I would be able to further my studies in the directions I want.

What I am trying to do is to get the most knowledge of most symbols in an elementary way, Instead of diving through topics. My assumption is that it will then be easier for me to dive into a specific topic.

I know there is Khan Academy, but I am a little bit old fashioned and my plan is to buy 10 books.

Comment: Look at the subjects named in the headings above the single tables, pick a basic introductory text on that subject.

Comment: Btw, that list is quite awful. I have no idea why they stress $\sum\sum$ as double sum when it is just the concept of sum ($\sum$) applied twice, whereas the use of the same symbol $\sum$ for both sums and series not even mentioned

Comment: "*My plan is to buy 10 books*"  It is unclear which symbols are those you know and which you don't from what you have described here.  It is not recommended to try to learn a subject if you are not mathematically mature enough for the subject.  Courses often have prerequisites listed in their course catalogue for a reason and as you get deeper into math you'll find that things don't neatly line themselves up... that eventually progressing in many different subjects simultaneously is ideal as they all draw examples from the others.

Comment: At best, knowing nothing about you or your current skill, I would recommend beginning where you left off or in highschool course material, and working your way through a traditional undergraduate math degree list of courses if you want everything from the shown list (*which gets into at least Linear Algebra, statistics, and multivariable vector calculus*).  Of course, the linked list only scratches the surface.  As you leave the undergraduate level difficulty, things get far more specialized and some notation only gets used at research level.

Comment: The end result is in my opinion... don't worry about not knowing things in maths.  Know that you don't know things.  That is just fine.  Be vaguely aware of what heights exist out of your reach for now.  Instead, know what you *do* know, and know where you might want to go next and what you need to do to get ready for it.

Comment: Actually why not simply use wikipedia ? This entry point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols will lead you to more detailed pages if needed. Then if you get an interest in a particular subject, why not consult a specialised book in a second step.

Comment: Relevant Feynman quote: "See that bird? It’s a brown-throated thrush, but in Germany it’s called a halzenfugel, and in Chinese they call it a chung ling and even if you know all those names for it, you still know nothing about the bird. You only know something about people; what they call the bird. Now that thrush sings, and teaches its young to fly, and flies so many miles away during the summer across the country, and nobody knows how it finds its way."

Comment: @jlammy But this is precisely why i want to learn about symbols through different relevant subjects, instead of just reading about what they mean

Comment: @zwim I have tried that but i keep getting into catch 22's in which the first detailed page I encounter, has symbols that I also don't understand and thus I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I can only recommend material in French, this pdf for instance is a very accessible introduction to calculus http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~pujo/fondmath1.pdf, hope you can find some equivalent in English.

Comment: @ jmoravitz what I am trying to do is to get to the most knowledge of most symbols  in an elementary way, Instead of diving through topics. My assumption is that it will then be easier for me to dive into a specific topic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested:
A history of mathematical notations, Florian Cajori 1928